# Is $\Delta[\det,m]$ smooth?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry

In [Geometric complexity theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5993) the following variety $\Sigma[\text{det},m]$ is crucial.

Let $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$ be a tuple of $r=m^2$ variables, so that $X$ can be thought of as an $m\times m$ variable matrix,
identifying $x_i$'s with the entries of $X$ in any way.
By a homogeneous symbolic determinant of size $m$ over $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$, we mean 
the determinant of a symbolic $m \times m$ matrix, whose each entry is a homogeneous linear function over $K$ of $x_1,\ldots,x_r$.
Let ${\cal X}$ be the 
vector space over $K$ of homogeneous polynomials of degree $m$ in the variables $x_1,\ldots,x_r$, and
$P({\cal X})$ the projective space associated with ${\cal X}$.
Let $\Sigma[\det,m] \subseteq P({\cal X})$ be the set of all points in $P({\cal X})$ 
that correspond to nonzero homogeneous polynomials in ${\cal X}$ that can be expressed as homogeneous 
symbolic determinants of size $m$ over $X$. 
Then $\Delta[\det,m] \subseteq P({\cal X})$ is  the Zariski-closure $\overline{\Sigma[\det,m]}$ of
$\Sigma[\det,m]$. Its dimension is $\le m^4$.

My question: is $\Delta[\det,m]$ smooth?

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/263760/zeta-function-of-delta-textdet-m without mention at either site.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not even normal by [the article of Shrawan Kumar](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/kumar/papers/kumar62.pdf).